# How to generate java wrapper for solidity contract with openzeppelin imports

Tags: java, solidity, openzeppelin, web3-java

Suddenly I discovered `web3j` provides an option to auto-generate the Java contract from solidity contract. Sample case you can find [here](https://kauri.io/#communities/Java%20Ethereum/generate-a-java-wrapper-from-your-smart-contract/).

Unfortunately it does not recognize the import of openzeppelin contracts:

```
Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> SwapValue.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looks like openzeppelin provides an option to add its contracts to your projects:

```
npx oz link @openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package
```

, but it lives in a separate environment rather than `web3j`.

Is there a known option to combine the all of them into one project?